# jQuery to validate a form (check for atleast 10 characters and certain value)

Tags: javascript, jquery

On my webpage I have a form where a user enters information for their article. Right now I use jQuery to check if the entered values are not empty, if they are I show an error message.

**Current validation**

```
//Story Form
$('.error').hide(); //Hide error message initially

$(".button").click(function() {         //On button click       
    $('.error').hide();  
    var title = $("input#sc_title").val();  
    if (title == "") {                    //if title is empty
        $("label#title_error").show();        //show error
        $("input#sc_title").focus();          //focus on title field
        return false;  
    } 
});
```

Right now it only checks if `title == ""`. How would I edit the code to also check if there are at least 10 characters entered e.g. if title is empty and less than 10 chars are entered, show an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if user puts 20 space character in the title field in that case title.length returns 20 and it satisfy true condition so you can use jquery trim also

```
if ($.trim(title) == "" || $.trim(title).length < 10) {
    $("label#title_error").show();        //show error
    $("input#sc_title").focus();          //focus on title field
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: so this only counts letter chars without spaces right? Really good I didn't think about it.

Comment: Oh and I guess just $.trim(title).length < 10 can do the job, so no title =="" is needed, right?

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if` to check the length instead - this will check anything less than 10 - ie empty too :

```
if (title.length < 10) {
   // Show error message
}
```

Really simple example : http://jsfiddle.net/GFjpg/1/

Comment: Just FYI, if you're checking for `length < 10` the `==  ""` check becomes redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan already removed as I saw the error of my ways !!! its still early and only had 1 cup of tea !!!!

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
if(title.length < 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

here's your code edited:

```
    $('.error').hide(); //Hide error message initially
    $(".button").click(function() {         //On button click

    $('.error').hide();  
      if ($("input#sc_title").val().length < 10) {
      $("label#title_error").show();        //show error
      $("input#sc_title").focus();          //focus on title field
      return false;  
    } 
    });
```

Comment: `$("input#sc_title").length` will count the number of elements in the array returned by the selector, not the length of the value in the field.